# how to use string vars in echo function

Tags: php, string, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I want to use this code in my header.php template in word press for using ACF plugin fields.
But it doesn't work. such as `href` attributes is not worked.

This is My code:

```
echo '<div align="center">';
//Rule Adress
if (the_field("rule") != 'http://' || the_field("rule") != '') {
    echo '<a href="' . the_field('rule') . '" role="button" class="Button Button--error" title="Rules" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i>Rules</a>';
}
//Cost
if (the_field("cost") != '0' || the_field("rule") != '') {
    echo '<a role="button" class="Button Button--info" style="cursor: default;"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-shopping-cart"></i>Cost: ' . the_field('cost') . ' Dolor</a>';
}
//Demo
if (the_field("demo") != 'http://' || the_field("demo") != '') {
    echo '<a href="' . the_field('demo') . '" role="button" class="Button Button--primary" title="Demo" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-heart"></i>Demo</a>';
} else {
    echo '<a role="button" class="Button Button--primary" title="Demo" style="cursor: default;"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-heart"></i>Demo</a>';
}
//Shots
if (the_field("shots") != 'http://' || the_field("shots") != '') {
    echo '<a href="' . the_field('shots') . '" role="button" class="Button Button--warning" title="Shots" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-desktop"></i>Shots</a>';
} else {
    echo '<a role="button" class="Button Button--warning" title="Shots" style="cursor: default;"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-desktop"></i>Shots</a>';
}
echo '</div">';
```

The fields `is-product`, `rule`, `cost`, `demo` and `shot` is my fields that are defined its in wp-admin.

Please Help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `the_field('field')` in your `if` statements use `get_field('field')` to return it as a value and not an object.

**For example:**

```
<?php if (get_field("rule") != 'http://' || get_field("rule") != '') { ?>
    <a href="<?php the_field('rule'); ?>" role="button" class="Button Button--error" title="Rules" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i>Rules</a>
<?php } ?>
```

You could also shorten this expression as follows:

```
<?php 
    $rule = get_field("rule")
    if($rule || $rule != 'http://') { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $rule; ?>" role="button" class="Button Button--error" title="Rules" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i>Rules</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @asherstoppard. I Cannot use the_field() with 'if' statements? are this code working without any error?

Comment: No problem at all, have did everything work for you after the amendments?